# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code in xcode when i run flutter project

Tags: xcode, flutter, macos

I have a flutter project on mac, when I run it in xcode i have this error and I am not used mac before and I want to fix this issue, I check for flutter path and try to run flutter project on web and it is work without any problem, but when I run the project on IOS simulator I get this problem,
How can I fix this issue, what should I do ?
[image]

Comment: You can try opening the project in xcode then under product tab > destination > any ios device... let it index and hope it runs...

Comment: @KeiCredo thank you, I try it but nothing change